# How to set a ** parameter in Python

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I'm newbie in Python.

I'm using Python 3.7.7 and Tensorflow 2.1.0.

This is my code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds

d = {"name": "omniglot:3.0.0", "data_dir": "d:\\tmp"}
omniglot_builder = tfds.builder("omniglot:3.0.0", builder_init_kwargs=d)
omniglot_builder.download_and_prepare(download_dir="d:\\tmp")
```

But I get this error:

> got an unexpected keyword argument 'builder_init_kwargs'

I want to set `data_dir`, but I don't know how to do it. I have tried to set `download_dir` in `omniglot_builder.download_and_prepare(download_dir="d:\\tmp")` but it stills download it to `~/tensorflow_datasets`.

From Tensorflow documentation for [tdfs.builder](https://www.tensorflow.org/datasets/api_docs/python/tfds/builder):

> **builder_init_kwargs: dict of keyword arguments passed to the DatasetBuilder. These will override keyword arguments passed in name,
>   if any.

How can I set `builder_init_kwargs` parameter value?

Comment: Don't name it `dict`, it's a built-in type in Python. Let's name it `d`. Then the syntax is `tfds.builder(name, **d)`.

Comment: @PéterLeéh Thanks. I have tried this `omniglot_builder = tfds.builder("omniglot:3.0.0", **d)` and I get this error message: *Argument 'name' passed by position and keyword in function call*

Comment: Remove the name in the dictionary, or don't pass name argument to the `tfds.builder`. The problem is you try to set the name twice.

Comment: @PéterLeéh Thanks. Now it works!!!! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the [docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/datasets/api_docs/python/tfds/builder), which say the `tfds.builder` method has type:

```
tfds.builder(
    name, **builder_init_kwargs
)
```

You want to do this:

```
dict = {"name":"omniglot:3.0.0", "data_dir": "d:\\tmp"}
tfds.builder(**dict)
```

The `**` syntax passes a variable as the kwargs, making the above code equivalent to:

```
tfds.builder(name="omniglot:3.0.0", data_dir="d:\\tmp")
```

Comment: Thanks. I have used this:`omniglot_builder = tfds.builder("omniglot:3.0.0", name="omniglot:3.0.0", data_dir="d:\\tmp")` and I get this error message: *Argument 'name' passed by position and keyword in function call*

Comment: That is because the first positional argument `name` can either be passed as `tfds.builder("omniglot:3.0.0", data_dir="d:\\tmp")` or as `tfds.builder(name="omniglot:3.0.0", data_dir="d:\\tmp")`, not in both ways.

Answer (score 1):

To set a kwargs argument in python, you have to simply add the ** before the argument itself.

So, this would be your code:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds

dict = {"name": "omniglot:3.0.0", "data_dir": "d:\\tmp"}
omniglot_builder = tfds.builder("omniglot:3.0.0", builder_init_kwargs=**dict)
omniglot_builder.download_and_prepare(download_dir="d:\\tmp")
```

Of course, I am just guessing, because I know what a kwargs argument is, but I am not familiar with tensorflow.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks. I have tried this `omniglot_builder = tfds.builder("omniglot:3.0.0", **d)` and I get this error message: *Argument 'name' passed by position and keyword in function call*

Comment: My guess is is that this error is caused because of the order of the order. Let me edit my code, tell me if that works.

Comment: Thanks. The order answer works and explain why. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you need a little help with argument packing and unpacking.

In the definition of a function or method, you specify the sequence of arguments that will be passed. If you want to have a variable number of input arguments, the mechanism is to "pack" them together into a list or directory. For example say you want to get the sum of all arguments given:

```
def get_sum(a, b): #only useful for two numbers
    return a + b

def get_sum(a,b,c): #only useful for three numbers
    return a + b
```

You would have to have a different definition for every possible number of input arguments. The solution to this is to use the packing operator to pack all arguments given into a list that can be iterated over

```
def get_sum(*list_of_inputs): # * will pack all subsequent positional arguments into a list
    x = 0
    for item in list_of_inputs:
        x += item
    return x

get_sum(1,2,3,4,5,6,7) #returns 28
get_sum() #returns 0
```

The same can be done for keyword arguments which get packed into a dictionary:

```
def foo(**keyword_args):
    for k in keyword_args:
        print(f'{k}: {keyword_args[k]}')
```

Now when you are using (calling) a function, sometimes you need to be able to "unpack" a list or a dictionary into the function call. The same operator is used to pack and unpack, so it looks very similar:

```
def foo(a,b,c):
    print(f'{a} + {b} = {c}')

arguments = ['spam', 'eggs', 'delicious']
foo(*arguments) #unpack the list of arguments into their required positions
```

Now finally on to your specific case: the function you are trying to use defines **kwargs in its definition. This means that it will take any subsequent keyword arguments and pack them all up into a dictionary to be used inside the function definition. The practical meaning of this is that you can provide keyword arguments to the function that aren't specifically defined in the function signature (this is particularly common when the function is calling another function and passing along the arguments). If you have already packed up your arguments prior to calling the function, it is easy to unpack them using the same process as shown by Oli: `tfds.builder(**dict)`